# Can i extend a Ruby class to behave like OpenStruct dynamically?

Tags: ruby, module, metaprogramming, mixins, openstruct

I have a Ruby class which includes a module. I want the including class to behave like OpenStruct. How do i achieve this without explicitly inheriting from OpenStruct?

```
class Book
  include MyModule
end

module MyModule
  def self.included(klass)
    # Make including class behave like OpenStruct
  end
end
```

instead of

```
class Book < OpenStruct
  include MyModule
end
```

Comment: Do you want to use OpenStruct class somehow or implement this functionality by yourself?

Comment: I want to use OpenStruct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could delegate all methods your class does not handle to an OpenStruct:

```
require 'ostruct'

class Test_OS

  def initialize
    @source = OpenStruct.new
  end

  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    @source.send(method, *args, &block)
  end

  def own_method
    puts "Hi."
  end

end

t = Test_OS.new
t.foo = 1
p t.foo #=> 1
t.own_method #=> Hi.
```

Comment: If you do this, you might want to look at the delegate class from the standard library instead of rolling your own: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Since `OpenStruct` is not a module, and you cannot cause modules to inherit from classes, you will need to write your own module that uses `method_missing` to implement the OpenStruct capabilities. Thankfully, this is very little work. The entire OpenStruct class is only about 80 lines of code, and most of that you probably don't even fully need.

Is there a strong reason you wanted to rely on OpenStruct itself?